# How to access internal services in production environment of Kubernetes from local machine? (Need: performance & security)

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, operation

I have a Kubernetes cluster running my production environments. I have bastion machine, and my own computer can connect to bastion & the bastion can access the cluster machines. I want to connect to some internal (i.e. not exposed to public network) services, such as MySQL, Redis, Kibana, etc, on my own computer. I need to have enough performance (e.g. the kubectl forward is toooo slow), and have enough security.

I have tried to use kubectl forward. But it is very slow, and after a search, they say it is just slow. So I guess I cannot make it faster.

I guess I can also expose every service as a `NodePort`. Then I can use things like ssh port forward. However, I am afraid **whether the security is low**? Because we have to create a NodePort, then if hacker can touch the cluster, he can use the nodeport to access my MySQL, Redis, Kafka, etc, which is terrible.

**EDITED**: In addition, I need not only my own computer, but my mobile phone to able to touch some services, such as my Spring Boot internal admin url. currently I do `ssh` port forward and bind to 0.0.0.0, so my mobile phone can connect to `my_computer_ip:the_port` to use it. But how can I do it without ssh port forward?

Thank you!

Comment: I can think of using something like Teleport though I am not sure if it is going to be slower/faster as it might still Kubectl under the hood.

Comment: A more VPN-like solutions such as Wireguard or Teleport is probably more of what you're looking for. Wireguard in particular is really easy to use in K8s.

Comment: https://github.com/shyiko/k8sovpn

Comment: @HarshManvar hmm it seems not very popular, and no commits recently

Comment: @VishalBiyani Hi I find teleport not very related to my case. could you please explain a bit? thanks

Comment: @coderanger Hi I find teleport not very related to my case. could you please explain a bit? as for wireguard, do you mean products like wormhole or kilo? thanks

Comment: Wireguard is https://www.wireguard.com/, they do not have multiple products or really any, that's it. As for teleport you can find info on app access here https://goteleport.com/docs/application-access/getting-started/. Wireguard is probably a better bet though since you want non-HTTP services too.

Comment: @coderanger thanks let me have a look, originally I did not find much about wireguard+k8s

Comment: It's not Kubernetes-specific, just a normal VPN that works well to bridge into cluster network space.

Comment: @coderanger sounds interesting. let me have a look

Comment: @coderanger hmm sorry I do not quite get it: wireguard seems to require modification to *every node* (kernel module) in k8s cluster, while we cannot do it because in k8s nodes are added & removed frequently

Comment: @coderanger hey I find this interesting article about OpenVPN + Kubernetes! Do you think this is also ok (besides the Wireguard)? Thanks! link --> https://itnext.io/use-helm-to-deploy-openvpn-in-kubernetes-to-access-pods-and-services-217dec344f13

Comment: Wireguard has been included with the Linux kernel since 5.6.

Comment: @coderanger unfortunately, our cloud provider's image has linux with version <5.6...... so what do you think of openvpn? I can change to wireguard later when my cloud provider gives 5.6